# Access Form Property with Instance VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

In Windows Forms (Vb.net) how can I access the properties without instance (new) ?

Form1.Property = "" ???  the property deceleration is not static? what is called this way of deceleration?

While you can't access Class1.Property!
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB.Net does some magic to allow you to pretend that forms don't have instances.

It creates a hidden shared instance, and converts static calls to instance methods (eg, `Form1.Show()`) into instance calls on this shared instance.

This is done for VB6 compatibility and should be avoided.

Comment: so what if I access form1.prop ? how about the other instances ?

Comment: @Sameh: That just calls the property on the hidden shared instance.  It compiles to something like `Form1.HiddenInstance.prop`.  It has nothing to do with nay instances that you create.

Comment: Thanks Slaks, but can we implement it with our own classes ?

Comment: Essentially VB automatically creates a global instance of every form, whether you use it or not.  If you wanted to do the same thing (though I would highly discourage it), you could create a global `Class1 As New Class1` variable.

Comment: @Sameh: No, and that's a good thing.  This behavior is unexpected and extremely confusing, and that's a good thing.  You may want to make a singleton.