# VB.Net form non-shared methods referenced as if they were shared?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am doing support on a VB.Net application although I am primarily a C# developer. I have encountered what I consider to be "strange" code, in that my C# mindset tells me that the code is wrong and shouldn't compile, yet it does. I did a *Find all references* on a particular form to see where it was being used and found references to the form where non-shred methods of the class were being directly referenced without the class being instantiated. In other words, I see code like this:

```
FrmCareer.ShowDialog(careerId)
FrmCareer = Nothing
```

Now *ShowDialog* is **not** a shared member, and it references instance member variables, so I would not expect intellisense to list the *ShowDialog* method at all. But it does and it compiles. Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VB.NET has the (very nice) feature of keeping a collection of all forms as properties under the [`My.Forms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87y2hdsf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) object. The objects there are instantiated when you first access them. In this way, you get a default instance of each form that you can refer to.

On the not so nice side, VB insists on importing the `My.Forms` object’s properties *globally*, and there’s nothing you can do to change that.

In other words, the class name of any form in your application doubles as a global instance of that form.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Konrad. So the code that I see where the previous developer sets the global references to _Nothing_ are probably wrong and could cause a null exception the next time the global reference is accessed?

Comment: @BruceHill Ah no, I forgot to mention this. The forms are re-instantiated automatically every time you try to access them. Setting them to `Nothing` is a bit weird but *should* work. This hearkens back to how VB6 did it – the first VB.NET version didn’t have this feature and VB6 developers were clamouring to have it included. I won’t comment on what I think of the general design except to say that you shouldn’t design frameworks while under the influence of drugs …

Comment: haha I quite agree! :) This feature does, I feel, introduce inconsistencies between forms and other classes are referenced. But at least I understand what it now! Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Is `FrmCareer` the name of the form?  If so, I think there's kind of a magic "singleton"-like variable for every form that you can access like this.  The idea being that the developer probably only wants one `FrmCareer` so any code can access it like this (to show the form, in this case).  In C# terms it would be like a global static.

Ah yes, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601503/access-form-property-with-instance-vb-net) - it has a better explanation.

Comment: Thanks, Rob. That link explains it well. :) But now that I understand it, I will take the global references out and replace them with actual instantiation of the form classes! ;) Thanks for the help.