# Why is the input from Form3 not recieved in Form2 after StartupForm has changed

Tags: vb.net, forms, input, startup

I have 3 Forms: Form1 (MainForm with Menu), Form2 (with ListView and Button) and Form3 (some Textfields and Button).

In Form1 I can open Form2 through the Menu. In Form2 I can open Form3 with the Button. In Form3 I can add the data from the input-objects to the ListView on Form2.

When I run the project and Form2 is the StartupForm everything works. When I run the project with Form1 as StartupForm I cannot add data from Form3 to Form2 anymore.

Form1:

```
    ' Open een venster om een productie aan te passen in de lijst met producties en pas de objecten in dat venster aan.
    Dim venster As New Form2
    With venster
        .Text = "Object " & actie
        .Btn_Opslaan.Text = actie

        ' Controleer welke acties er uit gevoerd dienen te worden (welke objecten krijgen welke waarde aan de hand van functie van het scherm).
        Select Case actie
            Case ACTIE_Toevoegen
                .Btn_Volgende.Enabled = True

            Case ACTIE_Aanpassen
                .Btn_Volgende.Enabled = False

        End Select

        .Show()
    End With

    venster = Nothing
```

Form2:

```
    ' Open een venster om een productie aan te passen in de lijst met producties en pas de objecten in dat venster aan.
    Dim venster As New Form3
    With venster
        .Text = "Productie " & actie
        .Btn_Opslaan.Text = actie
        If Cbo_Sets.SelectedIndex > 0 Then .Num_Verbonden.Enabled = True

        ' Controleer welke acties er uit gevoerd dienen te worden (welke objecten krijgen welke waarde aan de hand van functie van het scherm).
        Select Case actie
            Case ACTIE_Toevoegen
                .Btn_Volgende.Enabled = True
                .Lbl_ProductieWaarde.Text = "0"

            Case ACTIE_Aanpassen
                .Btn_Volgende.Enabled = False
                .Lbl_ProductieWaarde.Text = Lst_Producties.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(6).Text

                Dim i As ListViewItem = Lst_Producties.SelectedItems(0)
                .Num_Aantal.Value = Convert.ToInt32(i.SubItems(1).Text)
                .dtp_Tijd.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(i.SubItems(2).Text)
                .Num_Verbonden.Value = Convert.ToInt32(i.SubItems(3).Text)
                .Chk_Gemotiveerd.Checked = CBool(i.SubItems(4).Text)
                .Chk_Gilde.Checked = CBool(i.SubItems(5).Text)
        End Select

        .ShowDialog()
    End With

    venster = Nothing
```

Form3:

```
    '  Gegevens van productie toevoegen aan de lijst met producties in het vorige scherm.
    With Form2.Lst_Producties.Items
        Dim productie As New ListViewItem
        With productie
            .Text = Cbo_Producties.Text
            .SubItems.Add(Num_Aantal.Value.ToString)
            .SubItems.Add(dtp_Tijd.Text)
            .SubItems.Add(Num_Verbonden.Value.ToString)
            .SubItems.Add(Convert.ToInt16(Chk_Gemotiveerd.Checked).ToString)
            .SubItems.Add(Convert.ToInt16(Chk_Gilde.Checked).ToString)
            .SubItems.Add(Cbo_Producties.SelectedValue.ToString)            ' Het ID van de productie hoeft niet zichtbaar in beeld maar moet wel worden meegegeven.
        End With
        .Add(productie)
    End With

    Form2.Txt_Omschrijving.Text = "Geslaagd!"
```

It looks like a bug but I can imagine that I'm missing something here (in 99% of the cases the latter is the case!)

Comment: In Form3 you use the default form instance of Form2 (`Form2`) instead of what you did in the other forms. Why not do `Dim venster As New Form2` there?

Comment: I'm keen to know why you didn't rename these forms after you created them!

Comment: @ djv: Cause I don't need a NEW instance there because Form2 is already there.

Comment: @Casius: I did rename them but I thought it would be easier for you guys to read the code. (My names: Frm_Hoofdscherm (Form1), Frm_ObjectToevoegen (Form2) and Frm_ObjectProductieToevoegen (Form3), not really understandable names for non-Dutch speaking people)

Answer (score 0):

djv was right, I think

One of the most confusing (and irritating) things about VB.NET has its roots in VB6. In attempting to appeal to upgrading VB6 programmers, Microsoft made it so that every VB.NET app creates default instances of each of the forms, and the instance created is the same name as the type. This is wonderful for VB6 programmers who didn't have to really get into the difference between a Type and an instance, but it's a major irritation those of us who would look at a call to `Form2.Show()` and think "it's capitalized like it's a type, so maybe that's a static/shared method" but then realize "no, it's actually a non static/shared  method on an instance called `Form2`, made by a black box process hidden somewhere". VB.NET allowing instance variables named identically to the type doesn't help people appreciate the difference between instances and shared types either. `Dim String as New String, String.IsNullOrEmpty(String)` ahoy

Anyway. Back to the problem at hand

Your Form 3 shoves things into Form2's list, *but the Form2 it refers to is the Form2 that VB.NET made for you*. When you set the startup form to Form2, it is also this same instance of Form2 that appears. That Form2 makes a new Form3, the Form3, puts things in the `Form2` list, you see them because that's the Form2 that is on screen (The startup form is shown, the other forms are hidden)

When you make Form1 your startup form, that instance makes a NEW Form2 and shows it. That new Form2 shows a NEW FOrm3, but the FOrm3 that you see is still shoving its things into the Form2 that VB.NET made for you, which is invisible, because it's not the startup form

If you still didn't quite get it, put this code change in Form2 if Form2 is your startup object:

```
'BEFORE:

' Open een venster om een productie aan te passen in de lijst met producties en pas de objecten in dat venster aan.
Dim venster As New Form3

'AFTER:

' Open een venster om een productie aan te passen in de lijst met producties en pas de objecten in dat venster aan.
Form1.Text = "VB.NET made this form automatically and my visibility was " & Form1.Visible
Form2.Text = "VB.NET made this form automatically and my visibility was " & Form2.Visible
Form3.Text = "VB.NET made this form automatically and my visibility was " & Form3.Visible
Form1.Show() 
Form2.Show() 
Form3.Show()

Dim venster As New Form3
venster.Text = "SMoKuM made this form in code"
```

Or put this code change in Form1 if Form1 is your startup object:

```
'BEFORE:

' Open een venster om een productie aan te passen in de lijst met producties en pas de objecten in dat venster aan.
Dim venster As New Form2



'AFTER:

' Open een venster om een productie aan te passen in de lijst met producties en pas de objecten in dat venster aan.
Form1.Text = "VB.NET made this form automatically and my visibility was " & Form1.Visible
Form2.Text = "VB.NET made this form automatically and my visibility was " & Form2.Visible
Form3.Text = "VB.NET made this form automatically and my visibility was " & Form3.Visible
Form1.Show() 
Form2.Show() 
Form3.Show()

Dim venster As New Form2
venster.Text = "SMoKuM made this form in code"
```

Now use your app. You'll notice that whether you set form1 or form2 as your startup object, you get more windows than you expect, but things will always get added to the list with the form title bar saying "VB.NET made this auomatically" and the boolean at the end of the title bar should say whether the form was visible or invisible when the app started up

---

You may be able to avoid this terrible behavior by checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53116695/disable-default-instance-of-forms-in-vb-net)

Or using C# :)

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working now! Instead of using NEW i did this: Dim venster As Form2 = Form2

Comment: You could have just said `Form2` instead of `venster`, but I dig what you did there; giving yourself a different named variable than one that copies the Type is a good idea :)

Comment: Just to let you know: I up-voted your answer but my reputation is too low for showing it.

Comment: @SMoKuM Wait, isn't `Dim venster As Form2 = Form2` just a named reference to the default form instance?

Comment: Yes it is. So now I removed 'Dim venster As Form2 = Form2'.

Comment: @Caius Jard: Thanks for the update. I'm not familiar with C#. Is it so much better than VB.Net Basic? And is C# also a language in VB.Net?

Comment: It's marginally better as a language, it can do some things VB.NET can't (but you could also argue that the same sf true of VB); C# programmers are higher paid and it's regarded as more of a professional language, used by trained software professionals, whereas VB.NET is probably the preserve of self taught hobby programmers who do things in nasty, hacky ways (and it's fairly true; there are more programming sins in the vb.net tag here than in c# - anecdotal evidence of course - and the vb.net questions tend to be lower level or demonstrating less overall engineering knowledge form the OP)

Comment: To a true software engineer the language is actually just a syntax and some semantics, easy to learn. It's not a one or the other thing; many software professionals are happy to write either, or even other .net flavors like F# even if they never saw it before. These languages all compile to the same thing underneath and they have the same overall feel and engineering practices, just different keywords