# How to find a bindingsource contatins a particular column

Tags: vb.net

Respected Sir,
 Iam applying filter to bindingsource like this

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged
        If ComboBox1.SelectedValue > 0 Then
            Dim myID As Integer
            myID = ComboBox1.SelectedValue
            If myDataset.myTable.Columns.Contains("catid") Then
                BindingSource1.Filter = "catid =" & myID
            end if
       end if
```

But at the time of loading and closing the form, this gives an error that field "catid" doesnot exists.
How to find that bindingsource is binded to a datatable that has a particular column "catid" ? and applying filter if only it exists ?
yours faithfully
Murulimadhav

Comment: Do you know how to check `If (` the `TypeOf BindingSource1.DataSource Is DataTable)` ? Well `Then` ...

Comment: No, how to do that ?

Comment: I've already given you the answer. So `If ` it's a data-table then all you have to do is to `(DirectCast` the `(BindingSource1.DataSource` to `, DataTable` and check if any of the `).Columns.Contains` a column named `("catid"))` When done, `Then` apply the filter.

Comment: Try to apply the hints Mr Kringsa has given you, get as far as you can, then post/update your question.  It is too broad as it is.

Comment: If myDataset.myTable.Columns.Contains("catid") Then ... like this ??

Comment: where is that code located that it runs from *both* the Load and Close events?

Comment: one problem may be that event firing while the CBO is being created (not sure why it would fire in form *closing*). [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20158177/1070452) shows how to suppress that during load.

Comment: ok, we cant find particular column directly  by bindingsource.contains or bindingscource.Find .. method ?

Comment: that event *may* be getting called before the datasource is built, that is why I gave the link.  are you getting an error/exception, if so what is it?

Comment: Error message is "string contains a property that is not in the IBindingList,"