# Creating and using Form Instance giving error

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have created a simple form (Name RapidSales) in vb.net winform using visual studio 2010. I have datagridview1 on this form. Whenever i call to it by using the following code its successfully works:-

```
RapidSales.rgv.CurrentRow.Cells("ProductId").Value = myvalue
```

But whenever i create in instance of this 'RapidSales' form and then write and run the following code it gives me an error:

```
Dim winform As New RapidSales()
winform.rgv.CurrentRow.Cells("ProductId").Value = myvalue
```

Error message is following:-

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Please anyone help that how can i avoid this error and run my code successfully.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: More likely this one: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) . The other one is for Java

Answer (score 0):

While at its heart, this is another [NullReference Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26761773/1070452) it seems related to *how* you are using the form reference.  The question does not provide much context, so some guesswork is involved.

```
Dim winform As New RapidSales()
winform.rgv.CurrentRow.Cells("ProductId").Value = myvalue
```

Used in just that way, `winform` is a **new** instance of the `RapidSales` form; it is not an object reference to any existing default instance of `RapidSales`.  It is very unlikely that the `rgv` control (a DGV?) has any rows at all at this point, so the NRE results from referencing those null objects.

If `RapidSales.rgv.CurrentRow.Cells("ProductId").Value = myvalue` works, it means that the default instance of the form is already created and likely shown for the controls to be populated etc.   You probably want something like this:

```
' module/class/form level variable for the other form
Private winform As RapidSales

'... elsewhere when it is needed:
If winform Is Nothing            ' test if already instanced
    winform = New RapidSales()
    ' other setup stuff
End If
winform.Show()               

' else where use it:
Sub Something(myvalue As Integer)          ' no idea of the Type
    winform.rgv.CurrentRow.Cells("ProductId").Value = myvalue 
    ...
End Sub
```

More on [explicit form instances](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28290434/1070452)