# How can I watch Form1.vb variables from Module1.vb scope?

Tags: vb.net

In my Module1.vb code, if I assign a Watch to **Form1.Width**, I get the error "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference", and if I assign a Watch to **Form1**, I get the error "Form1 is a type and cannot be used as an expression"

However, `Debug.Print Form1.Width` works.

I read here
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262343(v=vs.60).aspx)
that

> Visual Basic creates a hidden global object variable for every form class.
>   It's as if Visual Basic had added the following declaration to your project: `Public Form1 As New Form1`

Is Visual Studio Watch insisting on accessing Form1 as a Class rather than as an instance (as in Debug.Pring)?

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Note that the article you linked is for VB6 not VB.NET.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20077246/1070452

Comment: Not for nothing but you have 6 questions with 6 answers, but have accepted none of them.  Accepting answers helps other users find good answers and says "thanks" to those who took the time to solve your problem. Upvoting *any* post answers you find helpful does the same.

Comment: Hey Plutonix, thanks for that. Since I'm still relatively new to the site, I wasn't aware I could/should "accept" answers... now I see the little checkmark, I've accepted an answer for each question. Your link is also informative, I think I'd have to play around a bit more to really get my head around it and the scoping issues I have.

Comment: If the [answer linked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20077246/1070452) was helpful, click the up arrow next to it to upvote it.  Upvoting also helps others find good answers.  They dont have to be answers to *your* posts.  The brief [Tour] explains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write your own code, using `Form1` in that way references the default instance.  The debugger doesn't support default instances.  You would need to assign the default instance to a field or property and then watch that.

One reason that the debugger doesn't support default instances may be that they are thread-specific.  If you break multiple threads and then wanted to watch a default instance, for which thread would you watch it?  I guess that you could default to the UI thread but then you are precluded from watching any other and it may also not be considered obvious enough.

Comment: I think maybe you ticked someone off (in this life or a previous one). +1